# Chartjs - show elements in all datasets on hover using bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

Is there a way to show the elements together when hovering on the same x-axis of a bar chart? Same with the image below.

[image]

I tried hover.mode ('single', 'label' and 'x-axis')

```
options: {
    hover: {
        // Overrides the global setting
        mode: 'label'
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it did not work for some reason. 
Is this not possible or did I miss something?

Code here: https://jsfiddle.net/jk4bg8a2/

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The property is actually stored in `tooltips` like this :

```
options: {
    tooltips: {
        // Overrides the global setting
        mode: 'label'
    }
}
```

Check your [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jk4bg8a2/3/) to see it working, and here is its result :

[image]

Comment: Yep, that's what I missed. Thank you!

Comment: @raz Since it helped you fixing your issue, consider [marking this answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Glad I helped though !

Answer (score 3):

For Chart.js 3, `label` mode is replaced by `index` and `tooltips` should be placed as `tooltip` in plugin object.

Below is working for chartjs 3.

```
plugins: {
  tooltip: {
    mode: 'index',
    position: 'average',
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For **Chart.js 3.7.1** this is what worked for me

```
options: {
    interaction: {
        mode: 'index'
    }
}
```

Documented under [ChartJs Interactions Documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/interactions.html#modes)